# How can I create a ClassLoader from a custom configuration in gradle?

Tags: class, configuration, gradle, dependencies, classloader

I have define a custom configuration and dependencies.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    myConfig
}
dependencies {
    myConfig   'org.foo:foo:+'
}
```

How can I create ClassLoader to load a class dynamically?

```
task myTask {
    def classLoader = configurations.myConfig.????
    def foo = Class.forName( "org.foo.Foo", true, classLoader ).newInstance();
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Do you want to dynamically load classes into your Gradle build script? Why? Can't you just use the regular `buildscript` block to configure the classpath of your build script?

Comment: @Jolta The classes are only used for some optional tasks. For the default build there must be 100% sure that there is no dependency. That I use additional configurations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this solution now. I hope there is nicer solution.

```
def classLoader = getClassLoader( configurations.myConfig )

ClassLoader getClassLoader( Configuration config ) {
    ArrayList urls = new ArrayList()
    config.files.each { File file ->
        urls += file.toURI().toURL()
    }
    return new URLClassLoader( urls.toArray(new URL[0]) );
}
```

Comment: While this is what a URLClassLoader is for, what you probably want is to add dependencies to your buildscript classpath directly.  See my answer below.

Also, you should definitely consider adding a parent classloader, if you want parent-loaded types to be shared by objects created from foreign classloaders.

Comment: Because we want also check that there are no missing dependencies in our list a parent classloader is a bad idea.

Comment: Groovyfication: `new URLClassLoader(config.files*.toURI()*.toURL() as URL[])`

Answer (score 0):

Move your configuration into the `buildscript { dependencies { classpath 'deps:go:here' } }`.  Then the classes are all automatically / correctly added to the gradle classpath (so you can reference types in them).

This is the "official" way of adding classes to your classpath.  Creating arbitrary objects Note that you can only configure buildscript {} at the very top of your gradle script.

If it's a dependency you want across all projects in your gradle build, you can  create a `buildSrc/build.gradle` where you just add dependencies to the runtime/implementation/compile classpaths: `dependencies { implementation 'deps:go:here' }`.

Comment: This would not work dynamically. For example if you need different versions of the same class in different configurations for different classloaders this would fail.